# How to check at least two words with jquery validation plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

So i have this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("tagcheck", function(value, element) { 
  var space = value.split(' ');
  return value.indexOf(" ") > 0 && space[1] != ''; 
}, "At least two words.");
```

Works perfectly, but if i have a space before the first character or two space between the words, its not working.

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has two spaces between the words:

```
var string = "one  two";
var space = string.split(" "); // ["one", "", "two"] There is a space between the first
// space and second space and thats null.
```

It has a space before the first character.

```
var string = " foo bar";
var location = value.indexOf(" "); // returns 0 since the first space is at location 0
```

What you want is to use a regular expression.

```
var reg = new RegExp("(\\w+)(\\s+)(\\w+)");
reg.test("foo bar"); // returns true
reg.test("foo  bar"); // returns true
reg.test(" foo bar"); // returns true
```

See [`.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) and [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

`\w` matches any alphabetic character. `\s` matches any space character.

Let's incorporate that into your code snippet for you:

```
var tagCheckRE = new RegExp("(\\w+)(\\s+)(\\w+)");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("tagcheck", function(value, element) { 
    return tagCheckRE.test(value);
}, "At least two words.");
```

Comment: Thanks:jQuery.validator.addMethod("tagcheck", function(value, element) { 
  return value.match("(\\w+)(\\s+)(\\w+)"); 
}, "At least two words.");