# jquery validator - Name must contain at least two words (e.g. 'John Smith') in a single text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validator.

I am having a text field and I want to apply validation as name shall not be **john** , it has to be **john smith** . please can anyone help how to add rule for the same.

Here is the code for text field and rule

```
       name_on_card: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },

     <input type="text" name="name_on_card" id="name_on_card">
```

can anyone suggest me in a single text field, how can i add validation so as it may accept two words.

I have tried this method but didn't worked properly.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("math1", function(value, element, params) {
 return this.optional(element) || value == params[0] + params[1];
 }, jQuery.validator.format("Please enter the correct value for {0} + {1}"));
```

Comment: maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843397/how-to-check-at-least-two-words-with-jquery-validation-plugin

Comment: What does [tag:jquery-validation-engine] and [tag:php] have to do with anything?  Please, you have enough reputation to know better than to tag-spam.  Edited.

Comment: If you cannot see that the `math1` function isn't even close to what you're asking, maybe you shouldn't be posting JavaScript related questions.  [As per the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _"Questions asking for code **must demonstrate a minimal understanding** of the problem being solved."_